# ajax post an update by submitting a form field with only the enter key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, submit

Fiddling with various combinations, the API for the node.js/mongoose .put is working (as tested with Postman, but the ajax seems to be defaulting on the submit.

On Enter, the page is refreshing and is adding the _id to the url even though it should just pass to the API
`http://localhost:4200/?storyID=537e835ffbc04d601bd39882`

Here's the HTML Form with an off-screen Submit field (would display:none be better?):

```
<form id="replyForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="storyID" id="storyID" value="\{{_id}}" />
    <input type="text" class="formFormat" id="newReply" placeholder="…" />
    <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
</form>
```

The current AJAX, which works perfectly for posting & finding, but has yet to save update posts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // POST
    $( "#postBtn" ).click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        // algorithms and postData..

        if (story.length != 0) {
          console.log('there is a story: ' + story);
            // make an ajax call
            $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            data: AjaxPostData,
            type: 'post',
                url:"http://localhost:1212/api/v1/stories",
                success: foundAllSuccess,
                error: foundAllFailure
            });
        };

    });

    // UPDATE
    $( "#replyForm" ).on( "submit", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        // e.stopPropagation();

        // get _id
        var id = $( "#storyID" ).val();

        // reply elements for API
        var reply = $( "#newReply" ).val();
        console.log(reply);

        var AjaxReplyData = {
            reply : reply
        };

        if (reply.length != 0) {
          console.log('there is a reply' + AjaxReplyData.reply);
            // make an ajax call
            $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            data: AjaxReplyData,
            type: 'post',
                url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories/" + id,
                success: foundAllSuccess,
                error: foundAllFailure
            });
        };

        console.log(AjaxReplyData.reply);

        resetForm($('#newReply'));

    });

}); // doc is ready
```

Comment: is this what you need: `$('input').keypress(function(e){ 
   if( e.keyCode == $.keyCode.ENTER || e.keyCode == $.keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER ){ e.preventDefault(); return false; /* ENTER was pressed */ } });`?

Comment: @DanielLisik that looks better, but the page still refreshes, displays the _id in the address bar, and has yet to save the data.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you use the code in my current comment? I think it should prevent the refreshing page.

Comment: I fixed the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/FBL93/1/

Comment: @DanielLisik where should the ajax update code be added?

Comment: In my updated fiddle I added a comment line where you could add the ajax update code. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/FBL93/2/

Comment: @DanielLisik thanks for that.. it's still refreshing though, and has yet to save.. quite curious

Comment: On my fiddle the page doesn't refresh. How did you implement my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54245/discussion-between-daniel-lisik-and-stackthis).